# Add categories column to the product grid in Magento admin

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a category column to the product grid.
I've modified `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`.
Added the following to `_prepareCollection` :

```
->joinField('category_ids',
            'catalog/category_product_index',
            'category_id',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            null,
            'left')
```

which gives me an error :
`a:5:{i:0;s:72:"Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "16243" already exist"`.

In prepareColumns I'm adding :

```
$this->addColumn('category_ids',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
            'index' => 'category_ids',
            'width' => '150px'
    ));
```

How can I fix my query so I won't get the error?
Is it possible to show and filter by category names instead of ids?

A forum post shows a similar code but I couldn't make it work with categories
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/44534/

```
static protected $COLUMN_ID_TRADE_REFERENCES = 'ref_text';

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('ref_text')
        ->joinTable('productreferences/reference',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            array('ref_text'),
            null,
            'left')
        ->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left')
        ->addStaticField('ref_text')
        ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(self::$COLUMN_ID_TRADE_REFERENCES,
            'GROUP_CONCAT(ref_text SEPARATOR " ; ")',
            'ref_text')
        ->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I’ve worked several days on this problem and have finally solved it. Since my solution is only one part of several product admin grid enhancements I have developed, I can’t show you a simple cut-and-paste solution. Instead, I will focus on **what** to do instead of **how** to do it. Of course I’ll provide as many code snippets as possible, but I cannot guarantee they will work on their own. Also, please note that the solution I describe has been tested with Magento 1.3.2.4 only.

First of all, the `category_ids` attribute of your products will most likely be of no use for you. This is a comma-separated list of category IDs (for example `206,208,231`). I assume that most people will not need the categories in that form. (If you do, you’re lucky, simply add a column containing the `category_ids` attribute to your grid and be done.) Additionally, as far as I know this attribute does not exist anymore in Magento 1.4.

The problem with this attribute is that it is just a redundant copy of the actual category assignment. The authoritative category information is stored in the table `catalog_category_product`, one row per product/category pair.

Since categories are *entities* in Magento and are not directly referenced via a product attribute, you cannot use `joinAttribute()` or `joinField()` with them. As far as I know, you cannot join *at all* entities of another type than that of the collection into it.

However, you can use `joinTable()` to put the category IDs into the result set like this:

```
$collection->joinTable(
    'catalog/category_product',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    array('single_category_id' => 'category_id'),
    null,
    'left'
);
```

As you’ve already found out, this has to be added to `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`’s `_prepareCollection()` function. The best way to do this, as always, is to create your own module and add a class that *extends* the Magento class. Since there is no way to cleanly hook into the original `_prepareCollection()` method, you will have to copy the whole method over to your overriding class and add the code there. (Remember to check for code changes in the original when updating Magento.)

We’re using a left join here, which will lead to multiple rows being returned for products having multiple categories. This is basically what we want, since we can then take the single category IDs (that’s why I called the field `single_category_id`) and translate them to the category name. However, the collection cannot handle multiple rows for the same entity (i.e. the same product). That’s possibly where your error message comes from.

Now, getting the category name is a bit complicated, since we cannot join other entity types into our collection. Therefore we’ll have to do it the dirty way and directly take the names out of the EAV database data for category entities. I’ve tried to stay as clean as possible and not hard-code any attribute type IDs or the like into the query. You will need some knowledge about [Magento’s EAV structure](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-database-structure-eav/) to understand what’s going on below.

Here’s how it works:

```
$res = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$eav = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$nameattr = $eav->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'name');
$nametable = $res->getTableName('catalog/category') . '_' . $nameattr->getBackendType();
$nameattrid = $nameattr->getAttributeId();
```

After this, `$nametable` will contain the name of the database table that contains the category’s name, `$nameattrid` will contain the numeric attribute ID for “name”.

Having this information, we can now join the correct EAV table manually into the query:

```
$collection->joinTable(
    $nametable,
    'entity_id=single_category_id',
    array('single_category_name' => 'value'),
    "attribute_id=$nameattrid",
    'left'
);
```

This will add a column `single_category_name` to our result rows.

Remember that we still have one row per category for multiple-category products. That’s what we’re going to fix next. To do that, we’ll have to group the resulting rows by the product ID and simultaneously concatenate all those `single_category_name` columns.

Grouping is relatively easy:

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

However, you should insert this *before* the code that joins the category name table. Don’t worry, I’ll show you a correctly sorted chunk of code at the bottom.

Concatenating the category names is somewhat harder. Since we manually brought in an EAV table, we cannot use `addExpressionAttributeToSelect()` on the category name attribute. Instead, we have to go down all the way to the Zend Framework database classes and manipulate the query there:

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(
    array('category_names' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        "IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(`$nametable`.`value` SEPARATOR '; '), '')"
)));
```

This retrieves the underlying `Zend_Db_Select` and adds a new expression column to it, which will concatenate the category names, separated by semicolon-space. Additionally, the `IFNULL` will take care of products not having any category at all, setting the `category_names` column to the empty string instead of a MySQL `NULL` value.

Let’s summarize it up to here:

```
$collection->joinTable('catalog/category_product',
    'product_id=entity_id', array('single_category_id' => 'category_id'),
    null, 'left')
    ->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
    ->joinTable($nametable,
    "entity_id=single_category_id", array('single_category_name' => 'value'),
    "attribute_id=$nameattrid", 'left')
    ->getSelect()->columns(array('category_names' => new Zend_Db_Expr("IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(`$nametable`.`value` SEPARATOR '; '), '')")));
```

In order to show the column, you have to add something like this to `prepareColumns()`:

```
$this->addColumn('category_ids',
        array(
            'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
            'index'    => 'category_names',
            'width'    => '150px',
            'filter'   => false,
            'sortable' => false,
));
```

The `filter` and `sortable` flags will prevent the column header to be clickable and also remove the filter text box for that column. Since we have done some heavy workarounding to get the categories column into the grid, these features won’t work anyway. I don’t need them, therefore I have not looked into how hard it is to make them work.

Now, if you have copied these two chunks of code into your installation, you’ll note that while the grid will correctly show the first page of results, above the table it will say that only one product has been returned and you won’t be able to paginate through the results. That’s because Magento uses a separate, automatically generated SQL query to count the number of results, and this method [does not work with GROUP BY clauses](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51137/). To fix *that*, we’ll have to override the collection class and add a workaround to it.

This is a class with that workaround:

```
class Our_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection {

    public $calculateSizeWithoutGroupClause = false;

    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        if (!$this->calculateSizeWithoutGroupClause) {
            return parent::getSelectCountSql();
        }
        $this->_renderFilters();
        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->from('', 'COUNT(DISTINCT `e`.`entity_id`)');
        return $countSelect;
    }

}
```

The `getSelectCountSql()` method is based on the original one (and even calls it if `$calculateSizeWithoutGroupClause` is not set), but additionally resets the `GROUP BY` clause.

Save this new class as `app/code/local/Our/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php` (or replace `Our` by whatever your module name is) and enable the rewrite by changing your `app/code/local/Our/Catalog/etc/config.xml` to contain a `<models>` block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Our_Catalog>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </Our_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_collection>Our_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Finally, setting

```
$collection->calculateSizeWithoutGroupClause = true;
```

in `_prepareCollection()` will enable our workaround for the admin grid and all is fine.

Comment: I had to use {{table}} in the second joinTable because of conflict with other part of the query. Can you explain what $countSelect->from('', 'COUNT(DISTINCT `e`.`entity_id`)'); does? The query works great but it is very slow. Any idea why? Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: The from() call adds a column to the SELECT. It counts distinct entity IDs, i.e. how many items were returned. This is the same behavior as in the original getSelectCountSql() method, the only thing we actually change is resetting the GROUP BY clause. I can’t confirm that the query is slow: In my shop, with about 2000 products and about 150 categories, the query takes less than 7 ms.

Comment: The original answer stated that we change the COUNT clause. This is not true, I’ve changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Per the quote above.

> The filter and sortable flags will prevent the column header to be clickable and also remove the filter text box for that column. Since we have done some heavy workarounding to get the categories column into the grid, these features won’t work anyway. I don’t need them, therefore I have not looked into how hard it is to make them work.

All you need to do is paste the code below

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$options = array();
foreach ($collection as $item){
    if($item->getId() != ''){
    $options[$item->getId()] = $item->getName();
}
}

$this->addColumn('category_ids',
        array(
            'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
            'index'    => 'single_category_id',
            'width'    => '150px',
            'type' => 'options',
             'options'  => $options
));
```

in place of

```
$this->addColumn('category_ids',
    array(
        'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
        'index'    => 'category_names',
        'width'    => '150px',
        'filter'   => false,
        'sortable' => false,
```

));

Comment: I'd add a "asort($options);" before adding the column, to display options alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to add the category (not the category path) and if the product has only one category, add this to the collection-setup:

```
$collection->joinAttribute('catname','catalog_category/name','category_ids',null,'left');
```

Comment: and what if some products have several categories?

Answer (score 1):

to display the name o all categories you can use

```php
$this->addColumn('category_ids',
        array(
                                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category'),
                                    'type'  => 'options',
                                    'index' => 'category_ids',
                                    'options' => $this->catOptions,
                                    'renderer'  => 'Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_List_Cat',
));
```

in your class block

```
 class Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_List_Cat extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $allCats = '';
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat)
        {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
            $allCats.= $_category->getName();
            if($key < count($cats)-1)
                $allCats.= ' ,';
        }
        return $allCats;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer but recently i saw this question so i'm answering as it can help others too.

Reference here: [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/is-there-a-way-to-add-category-column-to-admin-product-grid)

You have to create an extension to display category in product grid. Please create following files and it will work for you:

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid/Render/Category.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid_Render_Category extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $allCats = '';
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat)
        {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
            $allCats.= $_category->getName();
            if($key < count($cats)-1)
                $allCats.= ',<br />';
        }
        return $allCats;
    }

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/etc/config.xml` location and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Helper</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Block</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <admingridcategoryfilter>
                        <class>admingridcategoryfilter/observer</class>
                        <method>addCategoryFilterToProductGrid</method>
                    </admingridcategoryfilter>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Helper/Data.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Model/Observer.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model_Observer
{

    public function addCategoryFilterToProductGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if( ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid)  ) {
            $block->addColumnAfter('softprodigy_category_list', array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('admingridcategoryfilter')->__('Category'),
                    'index'     => 'softprodigy_category_list',
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'width' => '250px',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('admingridcategoryfilter/system_config_source_category')->toOptionArray(),
                    'renderer'  => 'admingridcategoryfilter/catalog_product_grid_render_category',
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterCallback'),
            ),'name');
        }
    }

    public function filterCallback($collection, $column)
    {
        $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($value);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($_category);

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Model/System/Config/Source/Category.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
{
    public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->load_tree() as $category) {
            $options[$category['value']] =  $category['label'];
        }

        return $options;
    }



    public function buildCategoriesMultiselectValues(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node, $values, $level = 0)
    {
        $level++;

        $values[$node->getId()]['value'] =  $node->getId();
        $values[$node->getId()]['label'] = str_repeat("--", $level) . $node->getName();

        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child)
        {
            $values = $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($child, $values, $level);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function load_tree()
    {
        $store = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $parentId = $store ? Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId() : 1;  // Current store root category

        $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')->load();

        $root = $tree->getNodeById($parentId);

        if($root && $root->getId() == 1)
        {
            $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($store)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

        $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);

        return $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($root, array());
    }
}
```

Create a new file on `app/etc/modules/SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter.xml` location and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now clear cache from cache management and you can see category column in product grid.