# Display category name in product grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to show category name for each product in admin grid. I did it like this and it works, but I am not sure is it correct way:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        /**
         * Tell Magento which collection to use to display in the grid.
         */

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(
                'catalog/product_collection'
        );
        $collection ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        $collection->joinTable(
            'catalog/category_product',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            array('my_cat'=>'category_id'),
                null,
                'left'
        );

        $collection->joinTable(
            'catalog_category_entity_varchar',
                'entity_id=my_cat',
                array('mv'=>'value'),
                null,
                'left'
        );
        $collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');

        $this->setCollection($collection);


        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me is it correct, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Compare your code to the answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3472702/2047249. That one works.

Comment: check the link stackoverflow.com/questions/3472702/add-categories-column-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-admin